# Pending euro payment to a usd account

Tags: international-transfer

Please I made swift transfer in euro from South Africa  to a dollar account in USA,my partner has not received the fund in his account and today marks the 7th banking day of the transfer which was made on the 11th of October 2017.

My question is can a correspondent Bank pend money transfer due to recipiant account is of a different currency and if yes what can I do from my side to ensure the money gets to my partner?
Awaits your response.

Comment: Sounds like you are scammed. How well do you know this ‘partner’?

Comment: My childhood friend.

Answer (score 1):

Currency exchange is rather the norm than the exception in international wire transfers, so the fact that the amount needs to be exchanged should have no impact at all.

The processing time depends on the number of participating banks and their speeds. Typically, between Europe and the US, one or two business days are the norm. Sending from Other countries might involve more steps (banks)  which each takes a bit of time. However, anything beyond 5 business days is not normal.

Consider if there are external delays - how did you initiate the sending? Was it in person with an agent of the bank, who might have put it on a stack, and they type it in only a day later (or worse)? Or was it online, so it is in the system right away?
On the receiver side, how did you/your friend check? Could there be a delay by waiting for an account statement?
Finally, and that is the most common reason, were all the numbers, names, and codes absolutely correct? Even a small mismatch in name spelling might trigger the receiving bank to not allocate the money into the account.

Either way, if you contact the sender bank, you will be able to make them follow up on it. They must be able to trace where they money went, and where it currently is. If it is stuck, they will be able to get it ‘unstuck’.